# std::unordered_map throwing an unhandled exception

Tags: c++

I have a std::unordered_map as part of a global variable of a struct type:

```
typedef struct level_locals_s {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> spawnVars;
    ...
} level_locals_t;

level_locals_t level;


...

...


void AddSpawnFields( char *key, char *value ) {
    level.spawnVars.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value);
}
```

The program crashes upon the insert. I have checked, and the key/value are correct. Here's where it crashes:

```
iterator begin()
{   // return iterator for beginning of mutable sequence
    return (iterator(this->_Nextnode(this->_Myhead), this));
}
```

this->_Myhead appears to be NULL. What would be the cause of this?

Using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010. 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000 is the error.

EDIT: Here is a compilable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef struct level_locals_s
{
    unordered_map<string, string> spawnArgs;
} level_locals_t;

level_locals_t level;

void main(char **args, int argc)
{
    string st1 = "key";
    string st2 = "value";

    memset(&level, 0, sizeof(level));
    level.spawnArgs.insert(pair<string, string>(st1, st2));
}
```

Comment: `std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>(..)` better use `std::pair<std::string, std::string>(..)` (if you need explicit template arguments) otherwise you might get problems with rvalue ref binding. (As seen in Stephan T. Lavavej's talk at Going Native.) **Note:** You don't even need the explicit template arguments, because of implicit conversions between to `pair` types. That would be the best solution `std::make_pair(key, value)`.

Comment: `typedef struct level_locals_s { .. } level_locals_t;` That's syntax from C, and neither required nor particularly useful or pretty in C++. In C++, just use `struct level_locals_t { .. };`

Comment: maybe you need to allocate the map

Comment: @Dru What about default construction?

Comment: "this->_Myhead appears to be NULL. What would be the cause of this?" Is `level` a global variable, and are you trying to access it at load-time?

Comment: level is a global variable, and accessed at runtime, yes.
The C syntax is due to the fact that this was originally C code at one point, and I'm doing refactoring of it to run better using C++.

Comment: Global variables are zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place. That would explain why some data is `0`. But it doesn't explain why it is *still* zero when you operate on it. That may have to do with the initialization order fiasco, but I cannot tell from the code you provided. Could you give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Thank you. Why do you use `memset(&level, 0, sizeof(level));`? (It's the source of the error, and not required.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because of this line

```
memset(&level, 0, sizeof(level));
```

`level_locals_s` is not a POD type even if you declare it the C-way (typedef struct), so calling `memset` on it will break the program in unexpected ways (maybe it is an undefined behavior?)

In C++, non-POD types are initialized by calling their constructor, which will do all kinds of initialization like allocating memory. Zeroing them out is not the proper way of initialization.

It seems that you come from C background and have much misunderstanding of C++. And by the way, the signature of `main` function should be `int main(int, char **)`

Comment: +1 But maybe you should mention that the (default) ctor is called automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I will use a struct constructor instead to handle the situation appropriately, as opposed to memset.

Comment: @eezstreet No explicit constructor or constructor call is required. The compiler automatically generates a default constructor for your `struct level_locals_s` and calls it for the global `level` during dynamic initialization. Just leave out the `memset` and it should work.

Comment: The stuff in level_locals_s gets cleared upon the level changing in the game, so I would need to clear it out somehow. Maybe via a method of it of some kind.

Comment: I mean a method for level_locals_s, not for unordered_map

Comment: @eezstreet: Then you need to write a method that clears all the member variables of `level_local_s`.

Comment: got here because I added a map into `CDescriptorHeapWrapper` copy pasted from the MSDN. That stuff had a memset(0), gg microsoft for the great coding standards.